What Biblical prophecies were fulfilled in or by the LDS Kirtland Temple?
In the final session of the April 7, 2024 General Conference of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, President Russell M. Nelson discussed the recent acquisition of the Kirtland Temple1 from the Community of Christ2 and mentioned some of the prophecies that had been fulfilled either due to the construction of the Temple or in the Temple itself.
I am seeking a comprehensive list of all the prophecies relating to or fulfilled in the Kirtland Temple as believed by members of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints. For each prophecy, please provide:

The Biblical reference to the original prophecy.
Either an LDS scriptural reference to the fulfillment of the prophecy or a link to a page on www.ChurchOfJesusChrist.org that explains the fulfillment.


1 "The temple functioned as a center of the Kirtland Saints’ worship, hosting Sabbath, prayer, and fasting meetings. Church leaders and missionaries assembled for study in subjects including reading, writing, history, and geography. The last session of the Kirtland School of the Prophets (also called the School of the Elders) was held in the temple." For more information about the Kirtland Temple, see Kirtland Temple
2 If it seems surprising that the Community of Christ owned the Kirtland Temple, please note that the Community of Christ was formerly known as The Reorganized Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints. The organization included early LDS membership who disagreed with Brigham Young's elevation to Prophet and remained east of the Mississippi river after many of the early church's membership left Nauvoo, IL for Salt Lake City, UT. It's not surprising that they had ownership of the property.

Though the prophet did mention prophecies of millenia being fulfilled, there was an early one that comes to mind found in D&C 88:117-126 (December 27 and 28, 1832, and January 3, 1833) see also (D&C 38:32 on January 2, 1831 and D&C 95)

117 Therefore, verily I say unto you, my friends, call your solemn assembly, as I have commanded you.
...
119 Organize yourselves; prepare every needful thing; and establish a house, even a house of prayer, a house of fasting, a house of faith, a house of learning, a house of glory, a house of order, a house of God;
...
126 Pray always, that ye may not faint, until I come. Behold, and lo, I will come quickly, and receive you unto myself. Amen.

Shortly after this commandment/prophecy construction of the Kirtland temple began.
The full quote by President Russell M Nelson, may be found at the end of the Sunday Afternoon session.

The Kirtland Temple has unusual significance in the Restoration of the gospel of Jesus Christ. Several events that took place there had been prophesied for millennia and were essential for the Lord’s restored Church to fulfill its latter-day mission.
The most important of these events occurred on Easter Sunday, April 3, 1836.4 On that day, Joseph Smith and Oliver Cowdery experienced a series of remarkable visitations. First, the Lord Jesus Christ appeared....
During this visitation, the Lord affirmed His identity. He said, “I am the first and the last; I am he who liveth, I am he who was slain; I am your advocate with the Father.”
Jesus Christ then declared that He had accepted the temple as His house and made this stunning promise: “I will manifest myself to my people in mercy in this house.”
This significant promise applies to every dedicated temple today. I invite you to ponder what the Lord’s promise means for you personally.
Following the Savior’s visitation, Moses appeared. Moses conferred upon Joseph Smith the keys for the gathering of Israel and the return of the ten tribes.
When this vision closed, “Elias appeared, and committed the dispensation of the gospel of Abraham” to Joseph.
Then Elijah the prophet appeared. His appearance fulfilled Malachi’s promise that before the Second Coming, the Lord would send Elijah to “turn the heart of the fathers to the children, and the heart of the children to their fathers.” Elijah conferred the keys of the sealing power upon Joseph Smith.
The significance of these keys being returned to the earth by three heavenly messengers under the direction of the Lord cannot be overstated. Priesthood keys constitute the authority and power of presidency. Priesthood keys govern how the priesthood of God may be used to bring about the Lord’s purposes and bless all who accept the restored gospel of Jesus Christ.
...
Then in the Kirtland Temple in 1836, the conferral of these three additional priesthood keys—namely, keys of the gathering of Israel, keys of the gospel of Abraham, and keys of the sealing power—was essential. These keys authorized Joseph Smith—and all succeeding Presidents of the Lord’s Church—to gather Israel on both sides of the veil, to bless all covenant children with the blessings of Abraham, to place a ratifying seal on priesthood ordinances and covenants, and to seal families eternally....
Priesthood keys give us the authority to extend all of the blessings promised to Abraham to every covenant-keeping man and woman. Temple work makes these exquisite blessings available to all of God’s children, regardless of where or when they lived or now live. Let us rejoice that priesthood keys are once again on the earth!
I invite you to consider carefully the following three statements:

The gathering of Israel is evidence that God loves all of His children everywhere.

The gospel of Abraham is further evidence that God loves all of His children everywhere. He invites all to come unto Him—“black and white, bond and free, male and female; … all are alike unto God.”17

The sealing power is supernal evidence of how much God loves all of His children everywhere and wants each of them to choose to return home to Him.


...
Here again, there is much we can learn from the sacred history of the Kirtland Temple.
Joseph Smith’s dedicatory prayer of the Kirtland Temple is a tutorial about how the temple spiritually empowers you and me to meet the challenges of life in these last days. I encourage you to study that prayer, recorded in Doctrine and Covenants section 109. That dedicatory prayer, which was received by revelation, teaches that the temple is “a house of prayer, a house of fasting, a house of faith, a house of learning, a house of glory, a house of order, a house of God.”
This list of attributes is much more than a description of a temple....

I don't see any other specific reference to specific prophecies being fulfilled. There are patterns that could be drawn from previous ancient temples in relation to Doctrine and Covenant sections. IMO I would place greater emphasis on the promises about temples mentioned above.
Referencing D&C 109 (dedicatory prayer) the footnotes mention:

1 Chronicles 16:7-36

Be ye mindful always of his covenant; the word which he commanded to a thousand generations; Even of the covenant which he made with Abraham, and of his oath unto Isaac; And hath confirmed the same to Jacob for a law, and to Israel for an everlasting covenant,... And when they went from nation to nation, and from one kingdom to another people;... Sing unto the Lord, all the earth; shew forth from day to day his salvation. Declare his glory among the heathen; his marvellous works among all nations.... Give unto the Lord, ye kindreds of the people, give unto the Lord glory and strength. Give unto the Lord the glory due unto his name: bring an offering, and come before him: worship the Lord in the beauty of holiness.


1 Kings 8:22-61

...God of Israel, let thy word, I pray thee, be verified, which thou spakest unto thy servant David my father. But will God indeed dwell on the earth? behold, the heaven and heaven of heavens cannot contain thee; how much less this house that I have builded?


Leviticus 19, Exodus 20 (Exodus 3:14) show the pattern of the Lord identifying himself with the phrase 'I am the Lord your God'

Referencing D&C 110 (Jesus, Moses, Elias, Elijah appear to Joseph and Oliver in the temple) footnotes mention:

2 Chronicles 7:12-16

And the Lord appeared to Solomon by night, and said unto him, I have heard thy prayer, and have chosen this place to myself for an house of sacrifice. ... If my people, which are called by my name, shall humble themselves, and pray, and seek my face, and turn from their wicked ways; then will I hear from heaven, and will forgive their sin, and will heal their land. Now mine eyes shall be open, and mine ears attent unto the prayer that is made in this place. For now have I chosen and sanctified this house, that my name may be there for ever: and mine eyes and mine heart shall be there perpetually.



The Appearance of Elijah and Moses in the Kirtland Temple and the Jewish Passover, Ricks 1983 (while not official LDS source, is from BYU which is LDS endorsed school), pages 485-486 mention:

[Moses'] appearance in company with Elijah offers another striking parallel between Mormon teachings and Jewish tradition, according to which Moses and Elijah would arrive together at the ‘end of time.’

In addition to previous mentions, focusing on the whole quote: prophesied for millennia and were essential for the Lord's restored church to fulfil its latter day mission I believe makes the focus on the restoration as a whole rather than the temple specifically.
Prophecies of apostasy/restoration (from last two references under See also)

JST, Gen 50:26
Daniel 2:45
Acts 3:21
Ephesians 1:10
Revelation 14:6
Micah 4:1-2
Isaiah 2:2
Isaiah 24:4-5
Matt 24:9-12
John 16:1-3
2 Thess 2:1-4

See also:

Joseph Smith and the Kirtland Temple 1836, Steven C. Harper
According to LDS, what principles of the gospel were corrupted in the Great Apostasy
Fulfilment of Prophecy, Elder Ronald A Rasband, Apr 2020 General Conference
Restoration of the Gospel, Gospel Topics

emphasis mine

What is probably meant is this:
D&C 110:13-16

13 After this vision had closed, another great and glorious vision
burst upon us; for Elijah the prophet, who was taken to heaven
without tasting death, stood before us, and said:
14 Behold, the time has fully come, which was spoken of by the mouth
of Malachi—testifying that he [Elijah] should be sent, before the
great and dreadful day of the Lord come—
15 To turn the hearts of the fathers to the children, and the
children to the fathers, lest the whole earth be smitten with a curse—
16 Therefore, the keys of this dispensation are committed into your
hands; and by this ye may know that the great and dreadful day of the
Lord is near, even at the doors.

Which is a (one of the) fulfillment of
Malachi 4:5-6

5 Behold, I will send you Elijah the prophet before the coming of
the great and dreadful day of the Lord:
6 And he shall turn the heart of the fathers to the children, and
the heart of the children to their fathers, lest I come and smite
the earth with a curse.

So much so that it is even cited in the vision. This happened in the Kirtland temple.
And there are probably lots of prophecies regarding the temple in the last days, which I am too lazy to look up, the fulfillment of which is ongoing but of course seen as starting with the Kirtland temple, by virtue of it being the first modern day temple.
